# MySQL query - select from one, count from another table

Tags: mysql

I have database with two tables - 'Warehouses' and 'Boxes'.
Each box has field with warehouse code, each Warehouse - 'capacity' field.

The purpose is to find only Warehouses that are "overfilled" (capacity of warehouse is less then number of all boxes with this warehouse code).

So, I count all boxes and join warehouse capacity by this query:

```
SELECT Warehouses.Code, Warehouses.Capacity, COUNT(Boxes.Code)
FROM `Warehouses` RIGHT JOIN
     `Boxes`
     on Warehouses.Code = Boxes.Warehouse
GROUP BY Boxes.Warehouse
```

Result:

```
------------------------------
Code | Capacity | COUNT
------------------------------
1    |    3     | 4
------------------------------
2    |    4     | 2
------------------------------
3    |    7     | 2
------------------------------
4    |    2     | 1
------------------------------
```

That returns me warehouse's capacity and counts boxes in it, but I don't know how and where to compare these numbers.

Comment: First depot looks overloaded (4>3) the others not. What do you need to do more? What is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this in a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT w.Code, w.Capacity, COUNT(b.Code)
FROM `Warehouses` w LEFT JOIN
     `Boxes` b
     on w.Code = b.Warehouse
GROUP BY w.Code, w.Capacity
HAVING w.Capacity < COUNT(b.Code);
```

Notes:

- `LEFT JOIN` is generally much easier to understand than `RIGHT JOIN` ("Keep all rows in the first table" versus "keep all rows in the last table, which I haven't read yet").  However, this query probably only needs an `INNER JOIN`.
- Presumably, `Warehouses` should be the first table, because your question is about this entity.
- The `HAVING` clause does the comparison after the aggregation.

Comment: `HAVING w.Capacity > COUNT(b.Code)` will get the warehouses where there is still capacity.. topicstarter asked for the "overfilled" warehouses where there to many boxes vs capacity... so it should be `HAVING w.Capacity < COUNT(b.Code)`